# Reading raster from mounted storrage via R in Ubuntu is unexpectedly very slow

Tags: r, raster, spatial, r-raster

I have a NAS attached to my network where I store different raster data. Now I want to access these data via R with my Ubuntu-Computer and my Windows-Laptop. The following (strange?) behaviour occurs:

Example 1 (netcdf-files)

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
a1<-Sys.time()
setwd(..path..)
a<-list.files()
for (i in 1:24){
    q1<-nc_open(a[1])
    q0<-raster(a[1],varname="wind_speed",band=i)/100
    nc_close(q1)
}
a2<-Sys.time()
a2-a1

>Time difference of 18 secs (Ubuntu, 1 Gbit Ethernet)
>Time difference of 32 secs (Windows 10, Wifi 5)
```

Judging the file size and the connection, this is kind of expected.

Example 2 (asc files)

```
library(raster)
setwd(..path..)
a<-list.files()
a1<-Sys.time()
for (i in 1:24){
    q1<-raster(a[i])
}
a2<-Sys.time()
a2-a1

>Time difference of 1.9 mins (Ubuntu, 1 Gbit Ethernet)
>Time difference of 3.2 secs (Windows 10, Wifi 5)
```

This is totally unexpected, since the setup is the very same, but instead of the ubuntu machine being twice as fast, the Windows machine is 40 times faster.

If I store the raster data locally on each machine, the reading time for the exact task is below 0.4 second each, as one would expect judging the file size and the read speed of the SSD.

I can reproduce the behaviour on another network with a similar setup. The Ubuntu machine is extremely slow when reading via raster() from an mounted network storage, all the other tasks run as expected.

Any idea, why this occurs?

Edit: I run some speedbenchmarks again, so don't mind the time difference between the table and the text. I think this should visualize the problem. Time is in seconds.

[speed benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41qWZ.png)

Comment: Any difference if you use `terra`?

Comment: @Chris good point! terra works quite interesting here: Example 2 with terra: 46 sec ubuntu and 1.53 min Windows.
In contrast, Windows on the second network speed up (5 sec vs. 9 sec terra vs. raster. Ubuntu on my second network : 1 min vs. 2 min; terra vs. raster

Comment: And you'll want to take all your raster ops to `terra` in any case...

Comment: What ever is the fastest. Since I know 3 seconds are possible, I just like to know where is the bottleneck in the ubuntu (and one Windows) example

Comment: not an answer, but there is no need to do `q1<-nc_open(a[1])` and `nc_close(q1)`

Comment: @RobertHijmans thanks, that was a testing leftover which is still in my script. I will delete it to save some time.

Comment: have a look at this, around minute 5 on, [xrprof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC9-QJ2mUWw) and ask yourself if this might represent your networked situation.

Comment: @Chris I run xrprof and it turned out that time is relativ. Reading a raster from a local SSD losts ~13 msec measured in R and 13 msec measured with xrproof. Reading a raster from the NAS losts ~4.63 sec measured in R and 70 msec measured with xrproof. The 70 msec is the time I actually expect.

Comment: The impression I derived was that, in addition to R related processing, one would get discrete info/timing on other aspects like network latency and thrash. Maybe over hopeful. But the difference, as to your setup, NAS lasts ~4.63 sec in R, lasts 70 msec in xprof, seems like a difference of 'signaling of completion', where xrprof may, in fact be right, and the diff(Sys.time) approach doesn't pick up properly, and how would you program something like, 'use the incoming results in < 90 msec whether available or not', to test the difference? Anyway, sounds like basis for `xrprof`? we hope to see.